# Count number of uniques depending on two lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to get some Excel help. I have a sheet with 3 columns:

- BusinessId
- Business_registration_ID
- Location_ID

One BusinessId can belong to one to many Business_registration_IDs in which case will appear in another row. Similarly, one businessId can also belong to one to many Location_IDs.

Per row, I'm looking to count the number of other unique business_registration_ids used at other location_ids that have also used the business_registration_id in the current row. For example:

| BusinessId | Business_registration_ID | Location_ID | # unique Business_registrations used at other locations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Business 1 | Registration 1 | Location 1 | 0 |
| Business 2 | Registration 1 | Location 2 | 0 |
| Business 3 | Registration 2 | Location 3 | 1 |
| Business 4 | Registration 2 | Location 3 | 1 |
| Business 5 | Registration 2 | Location 3 | 1 |
| Business 6 | Registration 2 | Location 4 | 1 |
| Business 7 | Registration 3 | Location 4 | 0 |

How do I go about calculating that?

Comment: You description and example doesn't match. `Registration 2 ` & `Registration 3` do not have other location_id. They have only one location id. Are you just want to identify unique `Business_registration_ID`?

Comment: Apologies - you're right. I've updated the example. The scenario is tricky to explain. I'm needing to identify unique Business_registration_IDs that belong to other locations that the Business_registration_ID is associated with.

Comment: Okay. Then `Registration 1` has other location. So, should also count. Any explanation?

Comment: Both location 1 and location 2 both use the same registration 1, so wouldn't count. I'm looking to count when the Registration between locations differs.

Comment: But for `registration 2` you also have multiple locations (both 3 & 4) then why count the location 3 as unique? And why count `location 4` with `registration3` as 0? There's no other locations with this registration.

Comment: have you looked at the use of countifs() with unique()?

Comment: Sorry all - I've updated the post again since my description was bad